# How to get all users which have more than 100 referrals?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a service which has a referrer system. There's table `users` in service's database which contains `id` and `referrers` columns. Column referrer contains a string of referrer ids that separated by `,`. Here's an example data from this table:

```
+------+---------------+
| id   | referrers     |
+------+---------------+
|    1 | 1             |
|    7 | 1             |
|    8 | 1             |
|    9 | 1             |
|   10 | 7,1           |
|   11 | 1             |
|   12 | 7,1           |
|   13 | 1             |
|   14 | 9,1           |
|   20 | 7,1           |
```

I need smt like: `SELECT id, login FROM users u WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM users u1 WHERE *referrers count more than 1000*)`, but I don't understand what should I use in `*..*`. To see this situation more clearly, I need to get the current user id from the first query and add it to the subquery into the `%LIKE%` statement, but how? Like:

```
`SELECT 
id, login 
FROM users u 
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT id FROM users u1 WHERE count((SELECT * FROM users u2 WHERE refer LIKE %u1.id%) > 1000)`
```

But how to do it in right way?

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't store CSV values that you wish to wish to query in SQL. Move the data to a junction table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string functions for this:

```
select id, login
from users
where char_length(referrers) - char_length(replace(referrers, ',', '')) >= 99
```

This works by counting how many `,` can be found in the `referrers` column: 99 commas means that there are 100 values.

Bottom line, you should fix your data model: instead of using delimited lists, you should have a separate table to store the user/referrer tuples, with one tuple per row. Storing delimited lists in a table column is typical antipattern in relational databases that should generally be avoided: you can read more about this in [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).